# How to make my apache web server public?

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I am a complete beginner at web development. I want to try accessing my web server through another device from another network. Likewise, I have managed to access it from the same Wi-Fi using my iPhone using my local IP, it ran similar to what I imagined but when I tried to connect to the server using another Wi-Fi it will not show anything (Connection timed out). I think I have tried port forwarding, but I couldn't find an exact solution for that. Thank you in advance.

An explanation of what any of the fillable slots means is very appreciated:

[image: Screenshot]

I have asked this on StackOverflow and Webmasters but it is off-topic there.

Comment: I am not sure about the image but the approach is to achieve that 80 port is redirected to your server local IP (i.e. 192.168.1.30) and to the port you configured your apache server (in most of the cases is the same port 80) check this url in the section of port forwarding, there is an image that can help you. https://linuxhint.com/setup_free_ssl_cert_apache_debian/ also at the end you should not try to enter externally with the local IP but with the Public IP (check https://www.whatismyip.com/ to know what public ip you have)

Comment: What you need is port forward. Also, you need to identify your public IP. Some ISPs dont allow hosting ports. Once you setup port forward, you the public IP of your network to access it.

Comment: @Mick_Mick the Right platform for your question would be SuperUser, since your are not Managing Business Env. So Your Question is even on here Offtopic.